# Привязка событий путём binding wpf.

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio

Приветствую. Есть код:

```
<Button Content="Click" Click="Binding Path=Funct"/>
private void Funct(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      MessageBox.Show("Test");
  }
```

Код нерабочий.
Задача следующая: нужно привязать событие к кнопке путем Binding. Как это можно сделать? 
Я читал, что можно сделать каким-то образом через Command интерфейс, но ничего не понял.

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего просто `Click="Funct"`. Если конечно `Funct` определено в code-behind.

Comment: А нужно ли его определять в code-bechind?  может во вью модели?

Comment: @Сергей: Если у вас обработчик в code-behind, то нужно привязывать через `Click="тут имя метода"`. Если обработчик в VM, то через `Command="{Binding тут свойство, содержащее команду}"`.

Comment: @Сергей: Какой из двух вариантов выбирать, это отдельный разговор.

Answer (score 2):

В WPF для этого есть команды, их уже и биндите. Вот [тут](http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level9/9_1.php) можете почитать про них

Comment: Я читал про команды, но так и не понял, как все-таки прикрепить к Button событие клика или наведение мышки на его или любое другое.